# IOS Programming - asynchronous json call to Spring Batch server

Tags: ios, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing an IOS app which is going to make asynchronous calls to a Spring-MVC back end which is protected by Spring Security.  I have been unable to figure out how this would work.  I have a web client which makes calls to this service (using jQuery Ajax), and I'd like to implement the same calls in IOS (iPad).

Is there any framework that would take care of handling authentication, then passing the token back and forth, as required by Spring Security?  How will the IOS application know to request userid/password from the user again after a timeout?

-- After doing some research, it looks like the IOS API already has functionality for authenticating (providing for Basic, Digest, Certificate and trust Authentication).  It looks like it is possible to throw up a dialog box to get a userid/password, then save it in an NSURLCredential object, and it will be used when necessary.

Am I correct with this?  Is there an easier way?  Does anyone have a simple example which illustrates how this authentication might work with a Spring-security protected server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use [AFNetwork](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to make my network API calls. The only problem that I have is the CookieTheftException that occurs when two connections with expired JSessionIds hit the server.